# database_tasks: false not working in rails 7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have 2 read replicas configured in the `database.yml` and I want to avoid any write operation in the Ruby on Rails application.

When setting `database_tasks: false` the following exception was raised:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activerecord-7.1.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:151:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>': 
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
in db_config.name
```

Is `database_task` deprecated or has it some bug after version upgrade?

**database.yml**

```yaml
service_read_replica_defaults: &service_read_replica_defaults
  adapter: postgresql
  username: root
  password: <%= nil %>
  host: localhost
  port: <%= 5432 %>
  database: <%= "service_#{Rails.env}") %>
  database_tasks: false

patient_read_replica_defaults: &patient_read_replica_defaults
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password: <%= nil %>
  host: <%= localhost %>
  port: 3306
  database: <%= "patient_#{Rails.env}") %>
  database_tasks: false

production:
  service_read_replica:
    <<: *service_read_replica_defaults
  patient_read_replica:
    <<: *patient_read_replica_defaults

development:
  service_read_replica:
    <<: *service_read_replica_defaults
  patient_read_replica:
    <<: *patient_read_replica_defaults

test:
  service_read_replica:
    <<: *service_read_replica_defaults
  patient_read_replica:
    <<: *patient_read_replica_defaults
```

There are two external databases (postgresql and mysql) want to connect with read only access. And I want to use `database_task: false` to restrict write actions on external databases.

Comment: What does your database.yml look like? What command did you run when you got that error?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful. Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.

Comment: @spickermann updated post with database.yml sample please look above

Comment: The updated `database.yml` looks like there is no primary database configured, only replicas. When there are only replicas with `database_task: false` configured, on what database do you want to run database tasks then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6b93fff8af32ef5e91f4ec3cfffb081d0553faf0/activerecord/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb#L104) is causing it to return false and hence db_config is returned as nil.
As the database.yml file contains only replicas and has **database: false** in each config, in the end no config is loaded and returned as nil. Hence, the error.
The solution we are looking for is that if there is any configuration that we are missing to add in our project or is this scenario missed by rails itself?

Just FYI, the error is occurring while running the command *bundle exec rails s*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).